# Includes vs hidden divs, which is better

Tags: php

Suppose I have this:

```
<a href="index.php?section_id=1">Section 1</a>
<a href="index.php?section_id=2">Section 2</a>

<div id="section_1">Code</div>
<div id="section_2">Code</div>
```

And then I have some code that gets the `section_id` and shows the DIV with number.

My question is, is it better to have it like that, or have two files just with that html and include it with PHP?

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to determine which approach is "better".  Both will work.  If one performs worse at scale than the other, run performance tests to find out.  If one is more difficult to read/maintain in the code than the other, refactor it when a pattern emerges.

Comment: How do I run a performance test? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would answer "_it depends_". oserk already wrote some arguments in his answer, another might be: Consider mobile users. They would rather like having all the data in one go (or would they?) instead of sending various request. Or consider ... This all depends on a) what you're trying to do b) who you're trying to do it for and c) what you're capable of

Comment: So there's a dilemma, if I put all the content in one page, that page is very heavy, but if i use individual pages there are more requests therefore more load time, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what are you tring to achieve. If you are serving only some static html or text you could pull it with include on server side. But if you have some dynamic content that would be altered on server in some way than I would recomend to pull it with ajax, via send the number only of the section and retreve it on frontend.

Hope that helps you, cheers

Comment: In my case, I have some static pages (they are like 10) and 2 dynamic pages, so you recommend me to make individual files for that 10 pages and put the content in the index in that 2 dynamic pages (for dynamic i mean php request and forms and stuff)

Comment: if the files are not to big sure, go for it!